# how can I extract all the url/links of a dynamic web page using python.I need this to verify for broken link for different web pages

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, phantomjs

need to extract all the links(image link,email-link,url) of a dynamic web-page in python

I have tried python "requests" module, but it works only with static web pages.

```
def get_html(url):
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    return html

soup = BeautifulSoup(get_html(url),features="html.parser")
for anchor in soup.find_all("a"):
    link = anchor.attrs["href"]
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    resp = requests.get(link,headers=headers, timeout=(2, 10))
    if resp.status_code in (400,404,403,408,409,501,502,503):
        isBroken = True
```

Comment: so you figured using selenium would be a good idea? what have you tried so far? please share your code

Comment: What you mean by "static"? With requests you fetch the page after that you have to extract somehow the links. One way of doing it could be by using [BeatifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: I have updated my code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use requests and lxml

Use requests to download the url content and use lxml to parse the content for urls.

code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree

r = requests.get('http://www.asciitable.com')

doc = etree.HTML(r.content)
for url in doc.xpath('//a[@href]'):
    print url.get('href')
    print requests.get(url.get('href'))
print r
```

output:

```
http://www.asciitable.com/
<Response [200]>
http://www.lookuptables.com/ebcdic_scancodes.php
<Response [406]>
http://www.lookuptables.com/
<Response [406]>
http://www.lookuptables.com/phoneticalphabet.php
<Response [406]>
http://www.unicodetables.com/
<Response [406]>
http://www.DialingCode.com/
<Response [200]>
http://www.Fezy.com/
<Response [406]>
https://www.ezoic.com/what-is-ezoic/
<Response [403]>
http://www.allconversions.com
<Response [406]>
http://link2me.com
<Response [406]>
http://www.perfume-click.co.uk/
<Response [200]>
http://www.asciitable.com/privacy/
<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: I  read somewhere that requests work with only static webpages, please suggest if the example above will also fetch information from a dynamic web page. This is the reason why I was using selenium with phantomjs

Comment: Just use Selenium then and leave BS4 out of it.  Selenium can find items in a webpage too.  `driver.find_elements_by_tag` and others.  When you find the link call element.click().